# Return an int array length n containing first n digits of pi? (c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, pi

Per the subject line I am trying to return an int array length n containing the first n digits of pi.

So MakePi(3) --> {3, 1, 4}

I know I need to get pi and it gets stored as a double. I need to convert the double to a char so that I can search through the array to find each char, n in length. Then convert it back to an int array.

I am having issues on where to go from here. I know there is a loop but I can't get my brain to figure out exactly what I need to do. Thanks!

```
public int[] MakePie(int n)
      {
        double pi = Math.PI;
        char newPi = Convert.ToChar(pi);
        char[] newArray = new char[n];
        newArray[0] = newPi;
        int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(pi);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {


        }
        return newArray;

    }
```

Comment: Clue: ToString() then ToCharArray()

Comment: Please note that basing your method on `Math.PI` will not give you more precision than `double`. For example, you cannot retrieve the 877th digit this way; a `double` has only [15–17 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) of precision.

Comment: I am not sure why you feel that it is necessary to convert it to a string. See my answer for a solution that skips the string entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: it will also get rid of the decimal.

```
public static int[] MakePie(int n)
  {
    double pi = Math.PI;
    var str = pi.ToString().Remove(1, 1);
    var chararray = str.ToCharArray();
    var numbers = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        numbers[i] = int.Parse(chararray[i].ToString());
    }
    return numbers;

}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks. I skipped the "var chararray" step though and this and it worked great. During the loop I did int.parse(str[i].ToString()) and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to return array of int**

```
var res = pi.ToString().Where(x => x != '.').Take(n).Select(x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Neat and compact solution

Comment: The result this gives me, 3 / -1 / 1 / 4 / ..., is bogus. Not everyone uses `.` as a decimal separator.

Comment: @hvd The question is about Math.PI. It is very, very , very simple to pass the decimal char as parameter for a method containing the above code.

Comment: Sure, but even though it is so simple, you didn't, and as a result, there are a lot of systems where your code doesn't do what you claim it does. I'm not claiming you're in any way required to answer with 100% strictly correct code, but if it isn't, and it doesn't work on the system of someone reading your answer, expect to get called on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require a string conversion, since your ultimate goal was to return an `int[]`.

```
 public int[] MakePie(int n){
    double pi = Math.PI;
    int[] result = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = (int) Math.Floor(pi);
        pi -= result[i];
        pi *= 10;
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int[] getPiVal()
        {
            string pi = Math.PI + "";
            int[] piarray = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                piarray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(pi[i] + "");
            }
            return piarray;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My strategy was to get each digit I wanted in the units position by multiplying PI by the relevant power of ten, and then getting the result of that number mod 10.

```
public int[] MakePi(int n)
{
    int[] result = new int[n]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (int)(Math.PI * Math.Pow(10, i)) % 10;
    }
    return result; 
}
```